# Ignore NaN when adding input values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
var inputsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function computeTotal() {
  var tot = 0;
  tot += parseFloat(inputsArray[0].value);
  tot += parseFloat(inputsArray[1].value);
  tot += parseFloat(inputsArray[2].value);
  inputsArray[3].value = tot;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text" disabled></input>
<button type="button" onclick="computeTotal()">Calculate</button>
```

It calculates fine when a number is entered in all three boxes, but I would like it to calculate even if a box is left empty, when in fact returns NaN.

P.S.: I know I could use a "for" loop and the isNaN() method to skip blank inputs, but I'm really looking for a solution for adding the inputs one by one.

I do not want to convert the NaN to 0.

Comment: `var val0 = inputsArray[0].value;
 tot += isNaN(val0 || val0=="")? 0:parseFloat(val0);`

Comment: just make default values of boxes as 0... or check and display validation when its not a valid number

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Multiply your value by 1 to cast it as an integer:

```
parseFloat(1*inputsArray[0].value);
```

Comment: Very simple and effective! Thank you!

Comment: That yields NaN when I run it with the value being an uncastable string (eg "bob").

Comment: It also does NOT **ignore** NaN.

Comment: It answers the question which was "when a field is empty". Obviously, it would be better to check the user input and prevent submit if the field can't be recongnize as a number

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for each line:

```
if (!isNaN(inputsArray[0].value)) {  tot += parseFloat(inputsArray[0].value);}
```

Comment: Thats wrong. the value ist not "NAN" but when you convert it to a float it returns "NaN".

Comment: Why ? i test if is not a number and if false i do the operation

Comment: explain your downvote ? cause this work i just don't check empty input

Comment: Ok I'll take the downvote back , though your answer does not directly relate to the question.
He is was looking for checking `isNaN()` **after** executing `parseFloat()` on the value.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) you can do something like the following:

```js
var inputsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function computeTotal(){
  var tot = 0;
  tot += (isNaN(inputsArray[0].value) || inputsArray[0].value=="") ? 0 : parseFloat(inputsArray[0].value);
  tot += (isNaN(inputsArray[1].value) || inputsArray[1].value=="") ? 0 : parseFloat(inputsArray[1].value);
  tot += (isNaN(inputsArray[2].value) || inputsArray[2].value=="") ? 0 : parseFloat(inputsArray[2].value);
  inputsArray[3].value = tot;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text" disabled></input>
<button type="button" onclick="computeTotal()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: I have chosen the simpler answer as correct; however this also worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Gramacho, you are most welcome. I appreciate you to accept the answer which serves your purpose best. Just to remind you, one draw back with the the answer you have accepted is, that will not work if any of the `input`s  mistakenly have strings like `hello, hi, john` etc. Because `1*hello` will give you `NaN`....thanks again.